# Phong-Alpha material transparency

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, glsl, qt3d

I'm using a pre-built material of Qt3D:

```cpp
Qt3DRender::QMaterial *MyClass::createMaterial()
{
    Qt3DExtras::QPhongAlphaMaterial *mat = new Qt3DExtras::QPhongAlphaMaterial();
    mat->setAmbient(QColor("#576675"));
    mat->setDiffuse(QColor("#5F6E7D"));
    mat->setSpecular(QColor("#61707F"));
    mat->setShininess(0.0f);
    mat->setAlpha(0.5f);
    return mat;
}
```

I set alpha to `0.5f`, so I expect the material be semi-transparent. But the model looks mostly white except some regions:

[image: Result]

When I check the [source code](https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qt3d.git/tree/src/extras/defaults/qphongalphamaterial.cpp?h=5.13.0) I see this settings for alpha-blending:

```cpp
m_blendState->setSourceRgb(QBlendEquationArguments::SourceAlpha);
m_blendState->setDestinationRgb(QBlendEquationArguments::OneMinusSourceAlpha);
m_blendEquation->setBlendFunction(QBlendEquation::Add);
```

I wonder why the model looks white?

---

As suggested by @Macke, the object on black background looks fine!

[image: black background]

When I set `alpha` to `1.0`, I observe this:

[image: alpha = 1.0]

---

### UPDATE

As pointed out by @Macke, one issue was related to depth test. On the [source code](https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qt3d.git/tree/src/extras/defaults/qphongalphamaterial.cpp?h=5.13.0), depth mask is disabled by default:

```cpp
// ...
, m_noDepthMask(new QNoDepthMask())
// ...

m_phongAlphaGL3RenderPass->addRenderState(m_noDepthMask);

m_phongAlphaGL2RenderPass->addRenderState(m_noDepthMask);

m_phongAlphaES2RenderPass->addRenderState(m_noDepthMask);
```

I enabled depth mask by removing `QNoDepthMask` stuff, and now with `alpha = 1.0` the rendering result is fine:

[image: enable depth mask, alpha = 1.0]

---

### UPDATE

Suggested by @EddyAlleman, I added such lines of code:

```cpp
blendState->setSourceAlpha(Qt3DRender::QBlendEquationArguments::Zero);
blendState->setDestinationAlpha(Qt3DRender::QBlendEquationArguments::One);
```

Then, the transparency (`alpha = 0.4`) is fine even on gray background:

[image: alpha = 0.4]

Comment: what version of Qt are you using? I'm asking because QPhongAlphaMaterial is marked as deprecated in the QtDocs.

Comment: @EddyAlleman I'm using Qt 5.13.0

Comment: You need to enalbe z-buffering / depth-test to fix that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this to set the blendequation state

```
set sourceAlphaArg to Qt3DRender::QBlendEquationArguments::Zero
set destinationAlphaArg to Qt3DRender::QBlendEquationArguments::One
```

**info from enum QBlendEquationArguments::Blending**

Constant                                    Value   OpenGL
Qt3DRender::QBlendEquationArguments::Zero   0       GL_ZERO
Qt3DRender::QBlendEquationArguments::One    1       GL_ONE

EDIT:
a good explanation can be found here: learnopengl.com/Advanced-OpenGL/Blending

Comment: It worked =) I did `setSourceAlpha` to `Zero` and did `setDestinationAlpha` to `One`. Now transparency works on gray background. I have no idea what's going on with these settings though!

Answer (score 1):

Try not using blendequation, seems like the color computed by blendstate is added to the gray background. (maybe good for got particle sparks, less so for objects)

How does it look with black background?

Comment: Wow! Thanks =) with black background the object looks fine. Do you know how to make it work with any background color?

Comment: Remove the blendequation state?  I'm not an expert on Qt3D, but I know my OpenGL. :)

Comment: Thanks! if I remove that, I guess OpenGL would use it's default blend function/equation. Right?

Comment: Yes. The default is to replace the color in the framebuffer with that what your blend  state computes. So, since you already mix it with the data, there, you don't want to do another add.